# WHERE IN ($array) AND something =?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have this, where `$results_array` is an array of imploded integers:

```
if ($stmt = $cxn->prepare('SELECT id FROM follows WHERE id IN (' . $results_array . ') AND user_id = ?')) {
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $user_id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $stmt->bind_result($temp);

    $final_array = array();
    while($stmt->fetch()) {
        $final_array[] = $temp;
    }

    $final_array = implode(',', $final_array);

    $stmt->close();
}
```

The problem lies in the query's `AND` check. If I remove the `AND` check, it works fine, but I need to have that check there. How do I fix this?

Comment: What's in your `$results_array`, exactly? What problem are you having? Empty result set? Error?

Comment: `$results_array` is this: `$results_array = implode(',', $integer_array);` where `$integer_array` is simply an array of integers. I meant to say that the query works fine, but it's not taking into account the `AND` check for each of the results in the array.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean, there is no `AND` check for the values in the array, the condition is met for any value (effectively an `OR` check): http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in

Answer (score 0):

Try to print on screen the $results_array in order to know the value of the array, then you can run the query to know exactly where is the error.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is using a question mark placeholder instead of a :colon, the line *$stmt->bind_param('i', $user_id);* wants to use 1 instead of 'i'. That or replace the SQL with *AND user_id = :i*